# restriction of a map is measurable iff the map is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have the measure space $(\Omega,F)$ and the map $T:(\Omega,F) \rightarrow (\Omega',F')$, where $A_1,A_2, \dots$ is a partition of $\Omega$ such that $A_i \in F$. The restriciton of $F$ to $A_i$ we call $F_i$ and the map restricted to $A_i$ we call $T_i$. Prove the following statement:

$T$ is $F-F'$ measurable iff $T_i$ is $F_i-F'$ measurable.

I think i proved from right to left, but the other side seem to bother me:

suppose $T_i$ is $F_i - F$ measurable, then $T_i^{-1} (F') \subset F_i \subset F$. Because this holds for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ we see that $T^{-1}(F') \subset \cup F_i \subset F$. Hence T is measurable.

For the other implication i'm kind of stuck. Any hints on how to start?

Kees

Comment: You are little bit sloppy. How does say $T^{-1}(\Omega')$ look like and how do $\bigcup_i F_i$ look like?

Comment: I know it is quite confusing, but this is the only info i got from the question.

Comment: It is not confusing. Your "proof" just has some technical problems

Comment: hmmm i see your point. I assumed that because $F_i$ is a restriction of $F$ to $A_i$, we have $F_i \subset F$,  And one can see that T is a function from $\Omega$ to $\Omega'$ if we unite all of the restricted $T_i$ functions right?

Comment: You do have $F_i\subset F$. The point is, how do you read $\bigcup_i F_i$. Is it just the union of the sigma algebras or the set of the unions of the elements of $F_i$'s?

Comment: o i see it as the union of the sigma algebra's $F_i$

Comment: What you probably meant is: For every $A \in F'$ it follows $T^{-1}(A) = \bigcup_i T_i^{-1}(A)$ which is a (countable) union of $F$ measurable sets, and thus itself measurable. Here, it is important that $A_i\in F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is $F-F'$ measurable. Given $A'\in F'$, $T_i^{-1}(A') = T^{-1}(A') \cap A_i$, which is in $F\cap A_i$.